# Android MSAL Configuration and Authority URL

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android#integrate-with-microsoft-authentication-library

The above document mostly works as captured. However, there are 2 areas that I need help on:

1. The MSAL Configuration that is generated in the Android configuration page on the AD portal is not similar. The "type" tag that is autogenerated is "B2C" but the documentation refers to "AAD"
   The authority URL specified in the document is "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common" which is deprecated.
2. I have attempted to substitute the AAD reference to B2C and authority URL to b2clogin.com but it doesn't work. Is there a different documentation that supports the new type and authority elements?

Comment: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common" isn't actually deprecated as this is not a B2C authority. It's the multi-tenant AAD authority and isn't the correct one to use here. The sample in the documentation looks to be for AAD apps, not B2C. The authority in B2C should be something like this: `https://yourb2c.b2clogin.com/yourb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin`.

Answer (score 0):

As @juunas said in the comments, `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common` is the authorization method for multi-tenant AAD, and it has not been deprecated. The B2C authorization method is different from AAD, the complete B2C authorization URL as follows: `https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}`.

Comment: Hi all, on Azure when you add a platform practically for android under authentication, platform configuration based on the steps, one gets the following MSAL configuration output {
"type": "B2C",
"authority_url": "https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}",
"default": true
}. This is different from the expected training output which is {
      "type": "AAD",
      "audience": {
        "type": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
        "tenant_id": "common"
      }
    }
has anyone seen this?